# Dropbox API - Error: expected list got dict

Tags: php, rest, dropbox-api

I am currently building a routine that needs to download files from one specific Dropbox folder , send them to another server and then move them to another folder on Dropbox.

I am using the `/files/move_batch` API endpoint for Dropbox to do so.

Here are the params sent to the API to move multiples files (well I'm only trying to move one file right now as it's still not working) :

```
$params = array(
            'headers'           => array(
                'method'    => 'POST',
                'content-type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                ),
            'body' => json_encode(array(
                'entries'           => array(
                    'from_path' => self::$files[0],
                    'to_path'   => '/Applications/Archives/' . substr(self::$files[0], strrpos(self::$files[0], '/') + 1),
                    ),
                'autorename'        => true,
                )),
            );
```

But I keep getting the same error message :

```
Error in call to API function "files/move_batch": request body: entries: expected list, got dict
```

I don't know what the API means by a list or how it should be formated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `entries` value should be a `list` of `dict`, one per file you want to move, each one containing both a `from_path` and a `to_path`. Your code is supplying the `entries` value to be a single `dict` though. (In PHP you can make both `list`s and `dict`s using the `array` keyword.)

It's easier to see and work with when you break it into pieces. Here's a working sample that does that.

```
<?php

    $fileop1 = array(
                    'from_path' => "/test_39995261/a/1.txt",
                    'to_path'   => "/test_39995261/b/1.txt"
                );

    $fileop2 = array(
                    'from_path' => "/test_39995261/a/2.txt",
                    'to_path'   => "/test_39995261/b/2.txt"
                );

    $parameters = array(
            'entries' => array($fileop1, $fileop2),
            'autorename' => true,
    );

    $headers = array('Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>',
                     'Content-Type: application/json');

    $curlOptions = array(
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($parameters),
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true
        );

    $ch = curl_init('https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/move_batch');
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlOptions);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $response;

    curl_close($ch);

?>
```

To move just one file using this batch endpoint, you would change that line to something like:

```
            'entries' => array($fileop1),
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Now I am trying to figure out how to build the entries param with many files...